# Phone not switching on

Tags: hardware

So I am using my Sony Xperia Neo L, and I accidentally dropped it on the ground and the battery comes out. This has happened hundreds of times before. When I insert my battery back in, the flashlight just turns on and the phone does not switch on. This happened for about half an hour. I then put my other battery to check (Yes I keep a spare) it does the same thing. Hours later, the flashlight doesn't come on, but when I try to switch it on, the red light is just beeping (as if the battery is low, but both my batteries are charged)..
What do I do? :(

Answer (score 0):

something must have happened to your phone's motherboard. Better get it to the service center instead of browsing through the internet for a solution. You cant do anything about it.

Comment: Aw man ;( .... Thanks, but is there any hope of it being able to get repaired ?

Comment: ofcourse you can get it repaired.
better take your phone to a service center you know personally. otherwise there is a chance of them telling out of the world things about your phone. Its always good to take it to the sony service center

Comment: Thanks alot :D! but i'm expecting it to be sort of costly